# How get to a nested array in object in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

From the array based on the index, I choose a specific element. Assigns to the `todo` variable. I check in console.log `todo`. It is object. Inside this object is an array. I try to iterate this array, but he returns me `body is not defined`

```
class Todo extends Component {
  render () {
    let todo = this.props.todos[this.props.index]
    console.log(todo);

    return (
        <ul>
            { 
              todo.messages.map((obj, i) => {
                <li>{obj["body"]}</li>
              });   
            }
        </ul>
    )
  } 
}

export default Todo;
```

---

**Console.log:**

```
Object
  id: 1
  color: "sdsdsd"
  messages: (2) [{'body':'sdsdsd', 'title':'678'}, {'body':'aaaaaa'}, 
    'title':'11111'],
  title: "fgfgfgg"
```

Comment: You forgot to add `return` to `<li>{obj["body"]}</li>`

Comment: or, you can remove the curly braces around the `li`. Then don't forget to add the key to that `li` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code's fine, except you have to return the result of the map function `return <li>{obj["body"]}</li>`.

Having such an error/warning `body is not defined`, it means some of your todo items, doesn't have a `body` property. Make sure all of your todos have a `body` property, or if the `body` isn't required, then conditionally render it.

Answer (score 0):

In that object that you consoled `messages` is not proper. I mean to say that the last element of `messages` is not in proper format. It is not an object.